# Is there any detailed tutorial or case study for building an online video delivery service using MPEG-DASH with HLS fallback?

Tags: http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash, media-source, dash.js

Is there any detailed tutorial or case study for building an online video delivery service using MPEG-DASH with HLS fallback? I find small pieces here and there but I can't put them together :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial gives you a step by step guide how to set up a Netflix-like streaming service with MPEG-DASH and HLS: http://www.bitcodin.com/blog/2015/02/create-mpeg-dash-hls-content-for-amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/

MPEG-DASH and HLS content can be generated using e.g. http://www.bitcodin.com. You can host it on any HTTP server or CDN. On the player side, you can use http://www.dash-player.com, which automatically detects the browser capabilities and chooses e.g. the MPEG-DASH stream (Web browser, Android, etc.) or HLS as fallback (iOS).